# How do I start a YouTube playlist from a video other than the first?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have a playlist with about 1000 videos in it. On its page, when I click an arbitrary video, it plays the video and shows me the playlist to its right. When the video has finished, a random video is played. I did not expect this.

If I click "play all" on the playlist's page, it starts at the beginning of the list, but only displays 200 videos to the right of the video player, so even if they were to play in the right order I can't select the one I want to start from.

Here's an example where I'm hovering over the "play next" button (mouse cursor not visible):

[image: The wrong video will be played next]

I was hoping that I just don't understand how playlists work and that I've misunderstood something basic. However, I have a suspicion that Google's UI design team has been involved and that all hope is lost.

Does anyone know how to work a playlist?

Answer (score 2):

You may have accidentally clicked on the shuffle button in the playlist.
Above the list of videos there should be two buttons Repeat and Shuffle, un-select the shuffle button and they should play in order.

[image: The Shuffle Button]

Comment: No, that's not it. Granted, the difference in appearance between the two states is almost non-existent.

Comment: Could you link to the playlist in question?

Comment: Sure https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5Qevr-CpW_yZZjYspehnFc-QRKQMCKHB

Comment: Nope everything plays perfectly  in order and once i get to video number 200 it loads an additional 100 in the black sidebar like i would expect it to.

Comment: Ok! Seems non-reproducible then. Can't be helped :)

Comment: I added a picture of the problem.

Comment: My experience is the same as SleepingGod's.

Answer (score 1):

You can always assemble it manually. By looking at URL, you can notice that it's build from 4 parts:

**<kbd>ADDRESS MASK</kbd> <kbd>PLAYLIST ID</kbd> <kbd>VIDEO ID</kbd> <kbd>INDEX NUMBER</kbd>**

For example, to start from 34th video from a given playlist:

**<kbd>https://youtu.be//watch?</kbd> <kbd>&list=PL5Qevr-CpW_yZZjYspehnFc-QRKQMCKHB</kbd> <kbd>&v=1nzx7O7ndfI</kbd> <kbd>&index=34</kbd>**

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?&list=PL5Qevr-CpW_yZZjYspehnFc-QRKQMCKHB&v=1nzx7O7ndfI&index=34**

**playlist ID**, **video ID** and **index number** can be put in any order you wish. Also, in the first item after **address mask** you can omit the **&** character. As already mentioned **Shuffle** button should be off for ultimate  chronological playback experience.

Comment: If you have to include the video ID, what's the point of the index number? If I click that link now, the index in the playlist is 32 now because the playlist changed. If I remove `index` from the query, I get the same result as any index value I set. If I keep `index=34` in the query but remove `v` youtube doesn't jump to #34 in the playlist, it just shows an error.